# looping over list of lists without nesting too much

Tags: python, list, indexing

So I have a list of lists called a, and I want to save the indices of an item inside that list in a tuple. for example, if `a[0][0] = 1`, then i would like to save `(0,0)` and save into that list.

Right now I have the ff code:

```
z = []
for i in range(0, len(a)):
    for j in range(0, len(a)):
        if a[i][j] == '.':
            y = (i, j)
            z.append(y)
```

This works perfectly, but I would like to get rid of the nesting, so I was wondering if there was an alternate way of doing this without nesting too deep.

Comment: I don't know that you gain much from changing this rather clear code that is easy to follow. YMMV of course.

Comment: On Python 2.x, `xrange()` is preferred to `range()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
from itertools import product
for i,j in product(range(len(a)), repeat=2):
    ...
```

Comment: `itertools` makes you strong! Strength crushes enemies! `itertools`! `itertools`! `itertools`!

Comment: Will this work if number of rows != number of cols?  Also, it seems like there might be issues for jagged lists.  I'd be interested to see how itertools might solve these issues, though! (I'm an itertools novice :)

Comment: @Closed, You can do `product(range(len(a)), range(len(a[0])))`. Won't work for jagged lists though

Answer (score 1):

You could use a list comprehension:

```
z = [(ii, jj) for ii, nested in enumerate(a) for jj, val in enumerate(nested) if val == '.']
```

However, I think your use of for loops is more clear.

**Edit**: Also, `range` by default starts at 0.

Answer (score 0):

some bs like this:

```
 z = ((i,j) for i in range(0, len(a)) for j in range(0, len(a)) if a[i][j] == '.')
```

i probably messed this one up - no python at home, but the idea is that you want a nested list comprehension with an if